# Get all E-Mail addresses from contacts (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, contacts

I know it is possible to pull up a contact and see information based on one contact. But is there any way to get all the emails from the contacts you have entered email addresses for and then store that in a NSArray?
This is my first time working with contacts so I don't know much about it.

Comment: Good Lord I hope not.  Can you imagine exposing that data to some random app?

Comment: I guess but it is for a client so I am just seeing if it is possible or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is possible, there must be some way to enumerate through contacts...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. It seems suspicious that you would want to do this (why do you need this information?), but it isn't difficult to do.

You can use `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` to get an CFArrayRef with all of the people, and then you can query `kABPersonEmailProperty` of each using `ABRecordCopyValue`. The code would look something like this (untested):

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
NSMutableArray *allEmails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:CFArrayGetCount(people)];
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
    ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++) {
        NSString* email = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);
        [allEmails addObject:email];
        [email release];
    }
    CFRelease(emails);
}
CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(people);
```

(Memory allocation may be a little off; it's been a while since I've developed Cocoa/Core Foundation code.)

But seriously, question why you are doing this. There's a good chance that there's a better solution by just using the Apple-provided APIs to present a contact picker at appropriate times.

Comment: Suspicious... burn it! Seriously, depending on how you implement this apple may reject :/

Comment: Oh yes, Alex is also right that this is the sort of thing Apple doesn't like.

Comment: I am doing this to provide an easy way to do an e-mail all contacts or sms all contacts. This is not for bad use.

Comment: Also I get an error in the [emails addObject:email]; line. The error is Bad receiver type 'ABMultiValueRef' (aka 'const void *)
How would I fix that?
And another thing, you gave the NSMutableArray and the ABMultiValueRef the same variable name? Was that intended?

Comment: Whoops! I just used the same variable name twice. I've renamed the `NSMutableArray*` to `allEmails` in the code sample above; that should fix it. Also, I've changed the type of `email` from `CFStringRef` to `NSString*` for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, works great! Also I am not sure if this is possible or not, but can you use the ABAddressBook and hide contacts from the list that do not have email address entered? In the end, I want to select certain people out of the list of people who have email addresses entered, then add them to an array. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. You can see that the outer loop is iterating over all of the people. So just take a look at `ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)`, which tells you how many email addresses the person has. Just check if it's non-zero, and then go ahead and add to your array. (Also, if this answer solves your problem, would you mind marking it as accepted? Thanks.)

Comment: oh sorry, I meant in the abaddressbookUI framework. That has a tableview of all the contacts, but I just want to hide the contacts in the tableview that don't have email addresses entered. Then I want to be able to select multiple contacts and then those contacts that are selected will be added to the array. Is that hard to do?

Comment: Not sure, sorry. If the AddressBookUI framework can't do it for you, re-implementing a similar view controller probably won't be too hard.

Comment: Even if we use apple's default view controllers, can we show the mail ids only of that person in the next view?

Comment: Why the OP wants to do this isn't relevant.  It's a valid technical question.  Answer it or don't, and leave out the pontificating.

Answer (score 20):

```
ABAddressBookRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(allPeople);
CFIndex numberOfContacts  = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(allPeople);

NSLog(@"numberOfContacts------------------------------------%ld",numberOfContacts);


for(int i = 0; i < numberOfContacts; i++){
    NSString* name = @"";
    NSString* phone = @"";
    NSString* email = @"";

    ABRecordRef aPerson = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allContacts, i);
    ABMultiValueRef fnameProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    ABMultiValueRef lnameProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);\
    ABMultiValueRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

    NSArray *emailArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty);
    NSArray *phoneArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneProperty);


    if (fnameProperty != nil) {
        name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fnameProperty];
    }
    if (lnameProperty != nil) {
        name = [name stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", lnameProperty]];
    }

    if ([phoneArray count] > 0) {
        if ([phoneArray count] > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < [phoneArray count]; i++) {
                phone = [phone stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [phoneArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }
        }else {
            phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [phoneArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }

    if ([emailArray count] > 0) {
        if ([emailArray count] > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < [emailArray count]; i++) {
                email = [email stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [emailArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }
        }else {
            email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [emailArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"NAME : %@",name);
    NSLog(@"PHONE: %@",phone);
    NSLog(@"EMAIL: %@",email);
    NSLog(@"\n");
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer as of iOS 6.0.

Comment: This is also better for me that i just need an email, as it returns the value stripped of unwanted data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
@import AddressBook;

- (void)addressBookInit {
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied || ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
//        NSLog(@"Denied");
        UIAlertView *cantAddContactAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Cannot get contacts" message: @"You must give the app permission to read the contacts first." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [cantAddContactAlert show];
    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
//        NSLog(@"Authorized");
        [self getEmails];
    } else {
//        NSLog(@"Not determined");
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil), ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (!granted){
                    //4
                    UIAlertView *cantAddContactAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Cannot get contacts" message: @"You must give the app permission to read the contacts first." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [cantAddContactAlert show];
                    return;
                }
//                NSLog(@"Authorized 2");
                [self getEmails];

            });
        });
    }
}

-(NSArray *)getEmails
{
    NSMutableArray *emails = [NSMutableArray array];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);
    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
    for (id record in allContacts)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)record;
        ABMultiValueRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty) ;
        NSArray *personEmails = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty);
        [emails addObjectsFromArray:personEmails];
        CFRelease(person);
        CFRelease(emailProperty);
    }
    CFRelease(addressBookRef) ;
    for (NSString *email in emails)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", email) ;
    }
    return emails;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**for iOS 9+, use Contacts framework, Objective C**

```
-(NSArray*)getAllContacts{
__block NSMutableArray *allContacts = nil;
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted == YES) {
        //keys with fetching properties
        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
        NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
        } else {
            allContacts = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                // create custom class Contacts with firstName,lastName,image and emailAddress
                for (CNLabeledValue<NSString*> *email in contact.emailAddresses) {
                    Contact *newContact = [[Contact alloc] init];
                    newContact.firstName = contact.givenName;
                    newContact.lastName = contact.familyName;
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                    newContact.image = image;
                    newContact.emailAddress = email.value;
                    [allContacts addObject:newContact];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}];
return allContacts;}
```