# I can't get the mail list by using mailcore

Tags: iphone, ios

These days ,I am working a mail client by using the mailcore.Everytime, Successfully connected to the imap server,but I can't get the INBOX list.The key code

```
CTCoreFolder *inbox = [account folderWithPath:@"INBOX"];
   NSArray *messageList = [inbox  messagesFromSequenceNumber :1 to:0 withFetchAttributes:CTFetchAttrEnvelope];

NSLog(@"%d",[messageList count]);
```

Evertime ,the output is 0;I do this is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `Address Book API` ?

Here are some answers:

[iOS how to get Email contacts from Mails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450631/ios-how-to-get-email-contacts-from-mails-app)

[Get all E-Mail addresses from contacts (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865436/get-all-e-mail-addresses-from-contacts-ios)